# Does $a*b=|a|b$ form a group over $\Bbb R-\{0\}?$

Tags: group-theory

Does $a*b=|a|b$ form a group over $\Bbb R-\{0\}?$

My progress so far:

1)$a* b=|a|b \in\Bbb R$ if $a* b=0$ implies $a=0 $ or $b=0$ which cannot happen .hence closure is satisfied

2)$a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c=|a||b|c$. associative property satisfied

3)$e*a=a$ implies $|e|=1$

Can both $1$ and $-1$ be identity?

i know that a group can only have one identity

If we consider $1$ then
$b*a=1$
$|b|=1/a$
We get inverse only for positive numbers and that also two inverses?

Comment: Use MathJax to rewrite your question.

Comment: @unknown See [this tutorial for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) regarding that first comment

Comment: $e\ast a=a$ implies $|e|=1$, so $e=\pm1$. Does $a\ast1=a$ for all $a$? What about $a\ast(-1)=a$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann is it good now?

Comment: @unknownuser Yes, well done!

Comment: $1$ is a left identity (as is $-1$) however there is no right identity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to consider $-1.$ What is its multiplicative inverse? That is, what $b$ solves $-1*b=|-1|b=1?$

Answer (score 1):

Since $1\ast b=b=(-1)\ast b$ for all $b$, it cannot be a group as it doesn't satisfy the [Latin square property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_has_Latin_Square_Property).

Comment: I am sure if I understand that property but what cannot we just choose one of them as identity and treat it as a group ?

Comment: What you have is a semigroup, @unknownuser. The idempotents of a semigroup are elements $f$ such that $f^2=f$. Here $-1$ and $1$ are idempotents. You can indeed take each as an identity of some subgroup of the semigroup. However, like you said, each group has exactly one identity; in fact, the identity is the only idempotent of a group.

Comment: so it is not group??if not then which of the fundamental property of group does it violate? Having unique identity is not necessary for being group right?

Comment: Like I said, it is not a group. Having a unique identity *is* necessary, @unknownuser.

Comment: Suppose $e,e'$ are identities. Then $e=ee'=e'$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4785714/104041) for whether there is an identity. That will give you some idea of what axiom doesn't hold.